# What's the name of this leafy brassica looking plant?

Tags: plant-care

I somehow lost the label for this beauty growing in my garden and I have no idea what it is. Can anyone help me???[image: The plant]

Comment: It looks to me  like collard greens.  Is it in a vegetable patch?

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like some time of Brassica plant maybe: broccoli, cabbage, cauliflower or kayle.

https://www.burpee.com/vegetables/brassicas/

Answer (score 2):

I think it looks like Collard greens, which are Brassica oleracea.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collard_greens